# Receive stream of text from Node.js in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, stream

I have an application built using MongoDB as database, Node.js in back-end and AngularJS in front-end.
I need to export to cvs format file some large amount of data from MongoDB and make possible to the user download it. My first implementation retrieved data from MongoDB using stream (Mongoose), saved the file using writable stream and then returned the path to AngularJS download it.

This approach fails for bigger files as it takes longer to be written and the original request in AngularJS times out. I changed the back-end to, instead of writing the file to disk, stream the data to the response so AngularJS can receive them by chunks and download the file.

Node.js

```js
router.get('/log/export', async(req: bloo.BlooRequest, res: Response) => {

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=\"' + 'download-' + Date.now() + '.csv\"');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');

  const query = req.query;

  const service = new LogService();

  service
    .exportUsageLog(req.user, query)
    .pipe(res);

});

public exportUsageLog(user: User, query: any) {

  let criteria = this.buildQuery(query);
  let stream = this.dao.getLogs(criteria);

  return stream
    .pipe(treeTransform)
    .pipe(csvTransform);

}
  
public getLogs(criteria: any): mongoose.QueryStream {

  return this.logs
      .aggregate([
        {
          '$match': criteria
        }, {
          '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users', 
            'localField': 'username', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'user'
          }
        }
      ])
      .cursor({})
      .exec()
      .stream();
}
```

This Node.js implementation works as I can see the data using Postman application.

My issue is how to receive these chunks in AngularJS, write them to the file and make the download starts in client side after changed the back-end to stream the data instead of only returning the file path.

My current AngularJS code:

```js
cntrl.export = () => {
  LogService
  .exportLog(cntrl.query)
  .then((res: any) => {
    if (res.data) {
      console.dir(res.data);
      let file = res.data;
      let host = location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host.replace("www.", "");
      let path = file.slice(7, 32);
      let fileName = file.slice(32);
      let URI = host + "/"+ path + fileName;
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = URI;
      link.click();
    }
  })
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
}

angular
  .module('log', [])
  .factory('LogService', LogService);

function LogService(constants, $resource, $http) {
  const
    ExportLog = $resource(constants.api + 'modules/log/export');

    exportLog(query: any) {
      return ExportLog.get(query, res => res).$promise;
    },

  };
}
```

With the above code, "res" is undefined.

How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.